# icefaces barchart shows bar stretched till end of x axis horizontally if only 1 bar is there

Tags: jqplot, icefaces-3

I am using icefaces 3.2. I have a ace:chart barchart . In simple words if i have only 1 bar to be shown in the bar chart , then the bar at runtime gets stretched till the end of X axis.

If i have only 1 bar to be shown then it should show only 1 slim bar and not a thick bar which stretches till the end of X axis - How can i achieve this.